# Batch Script to deploy Explicitly mentioned SVN revisions to Testing server

Tags: batch-file, svn

I want to write down a **Batch Script** in which I put (Enter) the revision number(s) and it deploys those revision numbers in sequence on a specific location of the Server.

Any help or a sample batch script in Windows would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Waseem Shahzad Bukhari.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want to perform a checkout for this

```
svn checkout -r <REVISION> <URL> <TO-PATH>
```

You can then later call

```
svn update -r <REVISION> <PATH>
```

to update to a later revision. This uses the data stored in the .svn subdir(s) to perform the least amount of work.

If you would use

```
svn export -r <REVISION> <URL> <TO-PATH>
```

you would also get the files from the repository, but without a way to connect them to where they came from.

Comment: Thanks, I dont think there would be any way in SVN Simple commands to Export only delta. Please share if any>